# Java: I Need to parse, modfiy and write back Java Source Files Programmatically

Tags: java, parsing

I need to parse, modify and write back Java source files. I investigated some options but it seams that I miss the point.

The output of the parsed AST when written back to file always screwed up the formatting using a standard format but not the original one.

Basically I want something that can do: content(write(parse(sourceFile))).equals(content(sourceFile)).

I tried the [JavaParser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) but failed. I might use the Eclipse JDT's parser as a stand alone parser but this feels heavy. I also would like to avoid doing my own stuff. The Java parser for instance has information about column and line already but writing it back seams to ignore these information.

I would like to know how I can achieve parsing and writing back while the output looks the same as the input (intents, lines, everything). Basically a solution that is preserving the original formatting.

[Update]

The modifications I want to do is basically everything that is possible with the AST like adding, removing implemented interfaces, remove / add final to local variables but also generate source methods and constructors.

The idea is to add/remove anything but the rest needs to remain untouched especially the formatting of methods and expressions if the resulting line is larger than the page margin.

Comment: I think you forgot to mention the main point... which modifications you need to do programmatically to source files?

Comment: Is this a tool request? That would mean its off topic for SO

Comment: Not really a tool request. I am looking for a solution. I hope that Java has some additional support or another way to reuse something in existence. I do not care if its a tool or part of it or something from oracle. I need a solution that is all. But I do not want to rewrite a AST implementation myself so I do not want to go the Antlr way.

Comment: I think the main point is: why do you need that?

Comment: @MartinKersten:  How is "solution" different than "tool"?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using antlr4 with its [java8 grammar file](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java8)

The grammar skips all whitespaces by default but based on token positions you may be able to reconstruct the source being close to the original one

Comment: If I remember correctly this will result only in a parse tree with a lot of capabilities missing like adding /removing elements and such? I would rather try a already existing solution. I can not believe that I have to solve this on such basic level. That is why I think I have missed something important. I would love to reuse an already existing open source solution. 

But you are right. This is the way to go if I have to build and generate my own parser solving this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if you need a rewritable syntax tree. Some simple transformations are possible by listening to parsing events and immediately emitting the transformed output. For more serious rewrites you need a rewritable AST, something what antlr does not provide. In such case you may build your own AST from the parse tree (quite lot of work for a complex language like java) or you may look for an other technology (I don't have any further idea)

Comment: Thanks for your input. You are correct with the AST is a lot work and that is exactly why I do not want to do it myself. There are some parsers out there but I hoped Oracle provides something like that out of the box or something. I found the javaparser project i mentioned exactly what I need but I never managed to get the output out of it what I put into... .

Answer (score 0):

The output of a parser generated by [REx](http://bottlecaps.de/rex) is a sequence of events written to this interface:

```
public interface EventHandler
{
    public void reset(CharSequence input);
    public void startNonterminal(String name, int begin);
    public void endNonterminal(String name, int end);
    public void terminal(String name, int begin, int end);
    public void whitespace(int begin, int end);
}
```

where the integers are offsets into the input. The event stream can be used to construct a parse tree. As the event stream completely covers all of the input, the resulting data structure can represent it without loss.

There is sample driver, implementing XmlSerializer on top of this interface. That streams out an XML parse tree, which is just markup added to the input. Thus the string value of the XML document is identical to the original input.

For seeing it in action, use the [Java 7 sample grammar](http://bottlecaps.de/rex/Java.ebnf) and generate a parser using command line

```
-ll 2 -backtrack -tree -main -java
```

Then run the main method of the resulting Java.java, passing in some Java source file name.

Comment: Thanks Gunther. Is a Java8 Grammar available?

Comment: Is also an AST implementation available?

Comment: No sorry, a Java 8 grammar is not yet available. Also there is no AST implementation that I could just point to. A transformation like you are aiming for could possibly be done directly on the concrete parse tree. Alternatively it might make sense to strip selected unit derivations from it, then perform the transformation on a thus stripped tree. That's what existing applications often do, some transforming XML in XSLT or XQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [Java Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/JavaFrontEnd.html) can do this.

DMS is a [program transformation system (PTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation), designed to parse source code to an internal representation (usually ASTs), let you make changes to those trees, and regenerate valid output text for the modified tree.

Good PTSes will preserve your formatting/layout at places where you didn't change the code or generate nicely formatted results, including comments in the original source.   They will also let you write source-to-source transformations in the form of:

```
  if you see *this* pattern, replace it by *that* pattern
```

where pattern is written in the surface syntax of your targeted language (in this case, Java).   Writing such transformations is usually a lot easier than writing procedural code to climb up and down the tree, inspecting and hacking individual nodes.

DMS has all these properties, including OP's request for idempotency of the null transform.

[Reacting to another answer:  yes, it has a Java 8 grammar]